# C# SQL Is it possible to insert from a joined table into datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have four tables in my SQL database

[image: Data relationship diagram]

In C# I have made a datagridview which shows the DeliveryDate, Quantity, Description and Price from the Order, Linkedtable and Stock table being joined in a select statement.

Here is the code used to join three tables into one datagridview

```
// this code for the load button of the datagridview
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT O.DeliveryDate, L.Quantity, S.Description, S.Price FROM [Order] O JOIN Linkedtable L ON O.OrderID = L.OrderID JOIN Stock S ON S.StockID = L.StockID ORDER BY O.DeliveryDate ", con);
        DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
        con.Close();
```

This is how the datagridview looks
[image: How the join statement looks in datagridview]

I would like to insert DeliveryDate, Quantity, Description and price from four textboxes into datagridview but i'm not sure how to do an INSERT statement with the tables joined like i have with the SELECT statement, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data will reside in different tables, there is no way to insert them at once and therefore, you can't execute it with one single command. However, you can create a store procedure to insert data into different tables separately, or you can insert them with two different INSERT commands in one batch.